# Can I export files from Adobe Flash Builder to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, flash, builder

We are planning to design a mobile app using Flash Builder instead of using plug-ins in Eclipse... I mean the GUI only.
Is that possible to import Flash Builder files into Eclipse?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

FlashBuilder is basically a customized version of eclipse.  Depending on which plug-ins you are using, and which files you want to import, you might even be able to use the exact same workspace.

Comment: hey thanks for sharing.
but i just found out that there is a plug in of Flash Builder for eclipse. =) THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Flex SDK installed into your eclipse IDE you should be able to export as an .fxp or you can import the project directory.